# z-index works on all modern browsers except Safari 7

Tags: css, safari, z-index

Here's a question for you CSS experts out there. The circle dragon and leaves in the upper corners of http://www.thedragonheart.com/ load in all modern browsers except Safari (I'm running 7.0.5) on the latest OS X or iOS. What's the dealio?

If I set div.overbg's z-index to 0 (instead of -1), the leaves and dragon appear, but then the dragon overlays the title in the header, and it prevents body text from being selected. I've tried upping the z-index on #wrapper, header, header a, and header a img, all to no avail. How can I make div.overbg appear over the background image while under the header and body text?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no `z-index` in your css in that website

Comment: in `style_custom.css` you have set `#flowerTR`, `#flowerTL` and `#dragonmark` to `z-index: -1;` why should you expect to see it properly? Why aren't you using positive numbers?

Comment: The reason those elements (it's class "overbg") use a negative z-index is so that the navigation bar and links in the body text are clickable. I've tried setting .overbg's z-index to 1 and #wrapper's z-index higher but links remain unclickable.

Comment: Have your tried some thing like this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/Tr2Yz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this in Safari 7 by setting the z-index to what it normally is, then giving the style block the additional rule of `pointer-events:none` which would still allow the underlying text/elements to be selected as normal.

Provided there are no click elements on that circle or dragon, everything would behave exactly like you're expecting it to.

Of course, this would blow away support for browsers that don't have a full implementation of CSS 3, but it's the world we live in these days.  You could always fall back to the negative z-index implementation for that scenario.

**Edit:**  Without going into too much detail on your CSS, the likely culprit of your second failed scenario (the z-index on the header not appearing above those elements with a z-index) is likely due to the header not being given a positioning value other than `static`.  You could probably fix this by giving it some stacking context by setting the CSS rule `position:relative;` on the element and then giving it a z-index greater than the stylistic elements.
*e.g.* `.dragon{z-index:1;position:absolute;} .circle{z-index:1;position:absolute;} .header{z-index:2;position:relative;}`

Comment: Setting position: relative and z-index: 2 on #wrapper and z-index: 1 on div.overbg did the trick! Thanks so much your royal Joshiness.